# [ROS] all rclcpp::AsyncParametersClient are notified for ros2 set param

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If there are multiple nodes and the rclcpp::AsyncParametersClient of each node implements `on_parameter_event`, all clients' callback are called when we do `ros2 param set some_node some_param some_value`. Is it an expected behavior?

Is there a way that only one client gets notified?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328312/%5Bros%5D-all-rclcpp::asyncparametersclient-are-notified-for-ros2-set-param/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is currently expected.
When you set/remove/update a parameter, a message is published to the `parameter_events` topic, that is shared among all nodes.
For this reason, the `on_parameter_event` callback will be triggered every time.

If you are interested only in specific parameters, you should check in the callback the parameter name and node before eventually doing something.

The ROS2 Parameters design states that it should be possible to subscribe only to changes to specific parameters, but this feature has not been implemented yet.

https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-07-12**:
Got it, thanks! As a follow-up, what is the equivalent API in C++ for `ros2 param set <node-name> <param> <value>`?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-07-12**:
Please open a new question or edit your original one to include this related question. Thanks! I can post a new answer or @alsora can take this into his answer if you add this question to you original question, but the equivalent API is http://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1SyncParametersClient.html#a267b96b3d93929404ac8ac4e83214831 (there is also an async version and this API works on a local or remote node by the given name).

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-07-12**:
Sure! I have opened a new question.